# Accessing a symlink via OpenSSH on Windows

Tags: ssh, symlink, openssh, net-use, mklink

I've installed OpenSSH server on Windows 10.  I've set up authentication using the `.ssh\authorized_keys` file, which works well.  I can now login from Linux/Windows/etc via ssh to Windows 10.

The user I am logging in as has a symbolic link in their home directory to a directory on a server, created via `mklink /d C:\Users\username\folder \\servername\path`.  I can access the symlink directory just fine as `username` over remote desktop, or locally.  However, when I try to access the symlink via ssh I get a permission denied error.

I can fix this by running `net use \\servername\path` after logging in via ssh.  So it looks like the issue has to do with credentials of some sort?  I would like to automate this process (or just fix the underlying issue) so that users can access `C:\Users\username\folder` without having to run a command on login.

My first attempt was to add the `net use` command to `.ssh/rc`, but that didn't work.  Does anyone else has some ideas on how to address this?

Some extra information:  If I log in with a password instead of an ssh keypair then it works fine.  However, I'd like to stick with the keypair approach, and I'm stumped on that route.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this yet?

Comment: @MichaelF Sorry, no - I gave up after switching to using https via IIS instead of ssh (which also ended up being way faster).  Good luck!